Translation of "not for many [people], but for few [people]"?
I am looking for the translation of "not for many [people], but for few [people]". Can I translate this phrase with "non omnibus, sed paucis"?
Thank you!

Your basic construction is right.
For word choice, I'm assuming "for many" here you actually mean "for everyone" (i.e. it's not for most people, just some). In that case, yes, omnibus is the right word here..
With the inclusion of a definite article (i.e. "not for the many, but for the few), a different word would be used. "The many" in Latin is typically "the crowd" (multitudo, vulgus, turba), although Cicero was fond of using multi (pl. subs. of multus), too. I'm not certain, but my hunch is that it's a calque from the Greek οἱ πολλοί (hoi polloi), which also has found its way into English.
If you're referring to "the masses", then I would suggest instead non multis, sed paucis

+1, and non multis, sed paucis is also simply the straightforward translation of the title question.

@richardIII How would that work? I don't see dedico being relevant at all, and dedico only uses ad + acc. when it refers to the act of handing over a dedicated object to something (e.g. spolia ad aedem dedicavit; cf. Vitruv. De Arch. 5.5.8).
